# Marvel Excalibur - What was the cause of Kylun's feline adult appearance?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, mutant

Question about Marvel's Excalibur (Vol I) series:

I'm curious about Kylun's (cool) feline adult appearance.

As a kid reading Excalibur, I had assumed Kylun was intentionally (and consensually) transformed over the years via the magicks of some Ee'rath mystic in order to craft a more effective and fearsome warrior.

But upon re-reading Alan Davis' second run on Excalibur, it dawned on me that Kylun's appearance may have just been another manifestation of his "normal" mutant abilities (besides the ability to exactly reproduce any sound).

Can anyone elucidate: what was the cause of Kylun's transformation from freckle-faced kid to his awesome adult appearance?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP Here. I posted this question on the official Alan Davis online forum, and [he answered](http://www.alandavis-forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=907)! Woo!

Here's the answer from Alan Davis (creator of Kylun) verbatim:

> My idea was that Kylun’s appearance was due to his mutant nature and
>   designed to suggest he had some sort of animalistic ability, that
>   helped him become a great warrior, in the hope his true power would
>   appear amusingly pathetic when it was revealed. With, hopefully, the
>   realisation that his fighting prowess is ‘earned’.

Answer (score 4):

His feline appearance is the physical manifestation of his mutation which included his abilities of sonic mimicry. His mutation also offered some physical enhancement of his strength and agility as well as his lion-like features and glorious mane of hair.

Comment: Thanks Thaddeus. Just wondering: do you have any reference you can cite for this info other than Wikipedia? Thanks again.

Comment: Big reader of Excaliber and its spin-offs for two decades. Would have to hunt it down in my collection but the wiki data is basically right, if a bit dull.